# Parse responses (batch) from Cloud Vision API in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-vision

I would like to pass a large number of requests to the Google Cloud Vision API for label detection - in Python. It all goes well. My problem is: how to read results?

Here's an example of a request:

```
{'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'my obj on gs'}},
 'features': [{'type': vision.enums.Feature.Type.LABEL_DETECTION}],}
```

and the code:

```
from google.cloud import vision

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
responses = client.batch_annotate_images(requests)
```

I send a list of requests with [batch_annotate_images](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vision/gapic/v1/api.html) and get [google.cloud.vision_v1.types.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html). I can't iterate through the response, there is also no method the interface that would be an obvious candidate. Here's what's available:

```
['ByteSize',
 'Clear',
 'ClearExtension',
 'ClearField',
 'CopyFrom',
 'DESCRIPTOR',
 'DiscardUnknownFields',
 'Extensions',
 'FindInitializationErrors',
 'FromString',
 'HasExtension',
 'HasField',
 'IsInitialized',
 'ListFields',
 'MergeFrom',
 'MergeFromString',
 'ParseFromString',
 'RESPONSES_FIELD_NUMBER',
 'RegisterExtension',
 'SerializePartialToString',
 'SerializeToString',
 'SetInParent',
 'WhichOneof]
```

The only thing I could come up with is:

```
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

json_result = MessageToJson(responses)
dict_result = json.loads(json_result)
```

It does the trick, but seems to be rather convoluted when compared to labelling a [single photo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/cloud-client/detect/detect.py#L123).

Is there a better way?

If not, I assume order of my requests passed in a list to `batch_annotate_images` matches exactly the response I get?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [getResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html) method to get a Java List of "annotatedImagesResponse", from which you can parse the information you need.

EDIT: There's no "getResponse" method in the [annotatedImagesResponse](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html) you got from that library. The response are in there as a [property](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html#properties) instead. You should be able to get a RepeatedField from it

Comment: I had the same idea. There is no such method on the object. AttributeError: 'BatchAnnotateImagesResponse' object has no attribute 'getResponses'

Comment: Interesting... I think I see the problem. There's no "getResponse" method in the [annotatedImagesResponse](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html) you got from that library.

The response are in there as a [property](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html#properties) instead. You should be able to get a RepeatedField<AnnotateImageResponse> from it.